# Hydrogen reactor, with electrolysis

Tags: electrolysis, hydrogen

I was thinking about hydrogen reactors. How they turn hydrogen and oxygen into water.

I just learned about electrolysis, so I was curious how efficient it would be, to fill a cars tank up with hydrogen and oxygen run it for a little bit and then capture the water, send it to an electrolysis chamber and have solar panels to turn it back into hydrogen and oxygen and repeat the cycle.

Comment: What you mean is a *fuel cell*, and you simply discard the water it produces. The electrolysis is done in a large plant.

Comment: Yes, that would work.You could also drop a ball from the second floor and then carry it up the stairs again. Or you can just let it roll down the street and take a new ball, like @Karl suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of achieving what you have thought about, is a fuel cell, as Karl mentioned in his comment. However, since you have asked about efficiency, I will try to address that question in particular.

What can be done is to produce the hydrogen at some factory, and then use the hydrogen as a fuel (like petrol) that can be loaded into the car to be oxidized in a fuel cell (with oxygen from air) and the resulting water vapor can be released into the air. This does not produce any $\ce{CO2}$, and seems like a green source of energy at first sight.

However, there are many problems that crop up when you try to implement this in the real world. One of the major problems is producing the hydrogen itself.

One source of the hydrogen is water. Electrolysis can produce $\ce{H2}$ but a massive amount of electrical energy is needed, so this is not a solution, it just passes on the problem to somewhere else. Solar cells (Photovoltaic cells) can be used, but they are not very efficient, so the process would not be economic. Nuclear power stations can work, but again , we are held back by the dangers and cost of building too many nuclear plants. Hydroelectric power is not available at all places, and it's overuse also harms the ecosystem. So overall, electrolysis is not economically viable if you want the energy to remain green.

Another source of hydrogen can be hydrocarbons. In fact one of the main sources of industrial hydrogen is the steam reformation of hydrocarbons. Natural gas (which is mainly $\ce{CH4}$) is reacted with steam at around 700-1100$^\circ$C with metal catalyst (e.g. nickel):
$$\ce{CH4 +H2O\leftrightharpoons 3H2 +CO \; \Delta H=+206 kJ/mol}$$
Water gas-shift reaction can produce more hydrogen:
$$\ce{CO +H2O \leftrightharpoons CO2 +4H2 \; \Delta H= -42 kJ/mol}$$

The overall process is endothermic so you have to burn something else to supply that, which creates more $\ce{CO2}$. A simplistic analysis would show you that using hydrogen obtained by this process, as fuel would generate 71% of the $\ce{CO2}$ that you would get from simply using the hydrocarbons as fuel (as we normally do). So, it's not a big difference in terms of carbon footprint.

However, fuel cells and traditional fuel engines work in different ways. The petrol or diesel engine is a heat engine, so its theoretical maximum efficiency is limited by Carnot's theorem. Experiments show that on road, the efficiency of delivering power to the road for a diesel engine is about 22%, which is very low.

A fuel cell is not limited by Carnot's theorem, and the theoretical maximum efficiency for a hydrogen fuel cell is 83%. Tests on road show the efficiency to be around 36%, so not a lot better than traditional engines$\mathbb{^{[1]}}$.

Still if you want to use hydrogen as fuel, a problem is carrying it in your car. Pressurised cylinders can be used to carry more hydrogen in low volume. Another potential way might be to use transition metals that can absorb (or perhaps more accurately, adsorb) large volumes of hydrogen.

And I am afraid fitting cars with solar panels to electrolyze the water is not a very good idea. The solar panel simply won't be big enough to produce the energy required to keep the process going. Remember that you are converting the solar energy to electrical energy, then chemical energy, and finally to electrical energy (fuell cell). In every step, there is some loss, so a far better idea is to simply use the electricity from the solar panel to run the car.

Several countries like Japan and Germany have already started considering vehicles that work on fuel cells. But, it is neither easy nor economic at this stage. So, let's hope that we can discover some source of green energy before all the fossil fuel runs out!

---

References:

1) von Helmolt, Eberle, *Journal of Power Sources*, **2007**, 165, p.833